# Cannot connect to database in jsp

Tags: java, database, jsp

I am trying to learn the database connection in jsp page. Here is my code:

This is my servlet:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("servlet");

    String username=request.getParameter("username"), password=request.getParameter("password");
    out.println("Username: "+username+" Password: "+password);

    CheckUser(username,password);
}

protected void CheckUser(String username, String password)
{
    dbConnect.connect();

}
```

And here is my dbConnect class:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;


public class dbConnect {

  static String dbUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Bank";
  String username="root";
  String password="";

  static Connection con=null;

  public static void connect()
  {
      try {
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
       con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
       System.out.println("Connected!");

      } 
      catch (Exception e) {

          System.out.println("not connected");

      }
  }

}
```

The problem is, in connect() function, when it comes to the line Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); it produces an error and enters the catch block. What is wrong here can anyone help? Thanks.

**Edit**: I did what Nambari said, now i get the error in the line **con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);** and here is the exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'bank'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:353)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:336)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1031)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2938)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:855)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3337)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1217)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1930)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:716)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:353)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.getInstance(Connection.java:295)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
at dbConnect.connect(dbConnect.java:18)
at loginServlet.CheckUser(loginServlet.java:41)
at loginServlet.service(loginServlet.java:36)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

not connected

Comment: What exception does it throw? add e.printStackTrace() in your catch block

Comment: Whats the `exception` type? Maybe you forgot to include `mysql`  library. It's a common error when doing things faster :-D

Comment: i do not know the type of exception it does not show in the error console, it just prints not connected. how can i see it?

Comment: Replace `e.printStacktrace();` instead of your naive `System.out.println();`. Also, I suggest seeing [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15981244/1065197) to learn the best way to handle the database connection. By the way, looks like you're missing the database connectivity jar (in this case, the jar to connect to MySQL), this jar and other third party libraries should go in *WEB-INF/lib* directory.

Comment: i edited question can you please have a look at it?

Comment: Now you forgot to use your user and password. Just change it to `con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, password);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `e.printStacktrace();` instead of your naive `System.out.println();` to see the errors and the messages about how to solve them. By the way, looks like you're missing the database connectivity jar (in this case, the jar to connect to MySQL), this jar and other third party libraries should go in *WEB-INF/lib* directory.

For your second error, you forgot to use your `user` and `password` variables. Just change it to

```
con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, password);
```

Note that you can get rid of all these problems if you use a database connection pool. Refer to [Is it a good idea to put jdbc connection code in servlet class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15981244/1065197) to learn the best way to handle the database connection.

Answer (score 1):

> Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); it produces an
>   error and enters the catch block.

Based on this information my guess is your `mysql.jar` is not in runtime classpath.

Comment: i went to properties>java build path>libraries and added the jar file. Isn't that what i am supposed to do?

Comment: @bigO: That add jars for build (compile time), not runtime. For Runtime, add it to lib folder.

Comment: I did what you said thanks, but now i get an exception in the next line can you please see the edited part?

Comment: @bigO: Check Luggi's comment.

Comment: @Nambari can you solve this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421506/android-xml-parsing-returning-the-node-name

Answer (score 1):

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'bank'
```

Indicates that your parameters for connecting to `mysql` are wrong. Please check the `user`, `password`, `host` and `driver` parameters.