# Integer parsing in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

This is just a simple query in Employee database using Employee ID where ID is an integer value. I did following operation to parse the value of ID in integer.

```
     String value = request.getParameter("Employee_ID");
     int id = Integer.parseInt(value);
  // Step 3: Execute a SQL SELECT query
     String sqlStr = "select * from Employee where ID = id ";
```

but it gives me following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Line breakpoint:QueryServlet [line: 45] - doGet(HttpServletRequest, 
     HttpServletResponse)
    - The value of the local variable id is not used
```

My html file:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Employee Details</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Employee Details</h2>
  <form method="get" action="http://localhost:9999/abcd/query">
    <b>Select Employee ID:</b>
    <input type="text" name="Employee_ID" value="ex101">

    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the error in your question? One is a breakpoint, and the other one an warning. I can't find any error in your question

Comment: @msrd0 the problem is that OP wants/need to use this `id` variable but it's not able to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using the `id` variable in your code. This is a literal string:

```
"select * from Employee where ID = id "
                                   ^ here id is part of the string, it's not the id variable
```

The naive way to make this work would be concatenating the variable to the String

```
String sqlStr = "select * from Employee where ID = " + id;
```

But **this is not the right way to create dynamic queries**. You should use a `PreparedStatement` and pass the parameters accordingly. This is how the code should look like:

```
//placeholder for id variable
String sqlStr = "select * from Employee where ID = ?";
//retrieve the connection to database
Connection con = ...;
//prepare the statement from the connection
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
//pass the id as parameter to the prepared statement
pstmt.setInt(id);
//execute the statement
ResultSet rs = pstmt.execute();
```

Also, make sure to split your code into layers. All this code related to the database connectivity and SQL execution belongs to a DAO layer.

More info:

- [Difference between Statement and PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3271249/1065197)
- [Is it a good idea to put jdbc connection code in servlet class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15981244/1065197)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
String sqlStr = "select * from Employee where ID = id ";
```

by

```
String sqlStr = "select * from Employee where ID = "+ id ;
```

However, you should read something about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: This is technically true but it's not the right way to do it.

Comment: Not only SQL Injection but code maintainability and SQL statement execution performance.

Answer (score 0):

Below should work:

```
String sqlStr = "select * from Employee where ID ="+id;
```

You have to concatenate the id to the query string that you wrote.

Edit as mentioned in the comments, its better to use parameterized query to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Similar to @Andres' answer, this is technically true but it's not the right way to do it.